# Problem in sharing post on company pages by API

Tags: linkedin-api

We were using JavaScript SDK to share the jobs on our company page but it is deprecated now and stopped working for us.

So please suggest a process because we are facing many problems in getting access token and API access (to share the post on company page) as at many places of LinkedIn documentation, it is written that we will need an approval for these API before use.

Also is there any approval process to get access of for the same?

Comment: Do you need approval to develop using the new API, or just to use it in a live situation? If you can start developing using it, then go ahead. Otherwise, just submit your request for approval now.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We need to start from basic as our old integration with Javascript stops working now. Can you please suggest the steps and any working example so that we can start with it easily.

Comment: Check this : This is with Auth 2 but with Linkedin V1 so this part you have to change :  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/log-in-with-linkedin-credentials/

Comment: Thanks KPSingh, but V1 is getting deprecated in March 2019 so we will need to use V2. Also, we will need to share post on our company page instead of login with Linkedin. Please suggest.

Comment: It looks like you are seeking more help than is generally offered by volunteers - I think this question is too broad and can be closed as such. Readers here really do want to help, but it is much better if you can identify a route to go down and make an attempt on it. If anyone works to provide you a full solution, it is not likely to fit your case based on design restrictions you have not stated.

Comment: If LinkedIn have deprecated an API then they will have documented an upgrade path (or marked it as discontinued completely). Have you found that documentation?